# Unresolved reference 'turtle'

Tags: python, import, reference, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was trying to import Turtle and Screen from turtle using the below code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen


nora = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()
```

but the editor(pycharm) shows-->

> "Unresolved reference 'turtle'"

and suggests to use "import turtle" to import entire module.

Kindly help.

[image]

Is this an issue with the editor?

Comment: You've already imported ```Turtle``` so you'd just do ```nora = Turtle()```  That's as far as I understand.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not an issue with the editor. When you use `from turtle import Turtle`, this doesn't import the `turtle` module as a whole, only the `Turtle` class from inside the `turtle` module.

So, you can do one of two things:

1. Import the module and access `Turtle` on it:

   ```py
   import turtle

   mora = turtle.Turtle()
   screen = turtle.Screen()
   ```
2. Import the `Turtle` class and remove the `turtle.` module namespace when you use it:

   ```py
   from turtle import Screen, Turtle

   mora = Turtle()
   screen = Screen()
   ```

Approach 2 is the preferred import because the `turtle.` module has 100+ functions added to it which represent a singleton turtle the module manages on your behalf. This singleton turtle can cause mix-ups with your instance turtles (the objects created with `Turtle()`). If you always import the `Turtle` class only, you guarantee that there won't be any mix-ups with the functional singleton interface attached to the `turtle` module.

It's even possible to skip the `Screen` import and access it via a turtle instance: `screen = mora.screen`.

The most dangerous import is `from turtle import *`, which is sometimes recommended for beginners because it reduces typing. But I never use this; it causes more harm than good, since not only does the potential for confusion between the functional and instance interfaces mentioned above arise, but also name clashes between your variables and the 120+ turtle functions polluting the global namespace can occur, leading to many hours of avoidable debugging.